# SQL Count number of rows until reaches a specific value

Tags: python, mysql

I'm doing a MySQL project where I need to retrieve how many *results/rows* are until the value is reached ordered by `points` row.

I did this, but it's a botched job code, and I guess I can improve it with a simple SQL using a `COUNT(value)` function.

```
#Python
sql = "SELECT nick FROM users ORDER BY points;"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()  
for row in result:
    rank += 1
    if nick == sender:
        print("you're rank number #" + str(rank))
```

Don't answer me with Python code, it's not needed. I just posted it to let you know what I am more or less trying to get.

Comment: So you are trying to get the first X rows?

Comment: @st0ph Mmm, yea quite accurate, I need to know how many users are before him

Comment: A better way to express what you want to do is to use sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're able to get an id from nick,

```
select count(1) from users where id < ?
```

where ? have to be substituted with user's id

Comment: Sorry I didn't say that i have to order the users by `points`, not `id`